# How to check if my data is one-hot encoded

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

If I have a data matrix, how do I check if the categorical variables have been one-hot encoded or not?
I need to use LIME to explain my prediction, and I read that LIME works only if you have category labels instead of one-hot encoded columns.
I found code to convert it, but it works only if it has been encoded otherwise the columns get turned to NaNs.

So I need e piece of code that looks at a numpy array with data and tells me if it has been one hot encoded or not.

Comment: According to "https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f" hot-encoded would mean that in one row there should be one "1" and the rest "0". Try writing code that does this and post it here. To get you started: a row validator could sort the values and then should always result in [1, 0, 0, 0, ...]

Comment: @576i please see the answer below and the comment; in general, this is not correct, as it implicitly assumes that only one OHE feature exists in the data, and it will not work in the general case of multiple categorical features that may be one-hot encoded (plus the presence of numeric features in the same row).

Comment: OK, in this case, why not repeat the check for each hot encoded feature? You could still write a row-based validator function. If you need more ideas, make sure to provide a suitable, repeatable example with the code you tried to solve this with.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum all the rows, and see if you get a all `1`'s array, as in the following example:

**Example:**

```
X = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]
    ]
)
print(f'X is one-hot-encoded: {(X.sum(axis=1)-np.ones(X.shape[0])).sum()==0}')
```

Result:

```
X is one-hot-encoded: True
```

Comment: Smart solution, but it implicitly assumes that `X` consists of a *single* (one-hot encoded) feature; in the general case where multiple OHE features are present it will not work.

Comment: Yep. I have a mixture of categorical and continuous variables